# Как получить список всех программ и служб, запущенных на андроид для дальнейшего анализа?

Tags: android

Делаю программу на андроид, с языком еще не определился, так как не знаю, каким образом решить проблему, связанную с получением списка запущенных процессов.

Я хочу получить список всех программ и служб, запущенных на андроид для дальнейшего анализа.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: С такими знаниями и вопросами прямая дорога на фриланс, поймите что за вас писать код никто писать не будет. От языка нечего не зависит

Comment: Я умею писать код, но я не знаю, каким образом мне получить список процессов на андроид. Проблем с этим на Windows у меня нет

Comment: Элементарно, тривиальная задача и гуглится за 10 секунд: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721994/get-info-about-all-running-processes

Comment: Я уже давно нашел решение, но все равно спасибо